# How to insert a constructed XML nodes in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, xslt-2.0, marklogic

I want to insert a node using below code but if i will rerun the code i don't want my node to be repeated twice-

```
let $doc := fn:doc("abc.xml")

(: abc.xml looks like--

<root>
  <value1>somevalue</value1>
  <value2>somevalue</value2>
  <value3>somevalue</value3>
  <value4>somevalue</value4>
  <value5>Australia</value5>
  <value6>India</value6>
  <value7>USA</value7>
  <value8>somevalue</value8>
  <value9>somevalue</value9>
  <value10>somevalue</value10>
</root> :)

let $element :=  element Root{
                    element A{"A"},
                    element B{"B"},
                    element C{"C"},
                    element D{"D"},
                    element E{"E"}
                }  

let $doc := xdmp:node-insert-after(doc("abc.xml")//value4, $element) 
return doc("abc.xml")
```

Whenever i am running this query my `ELEMENT` is getting inserted after `value4` but i want that if i am running this multiple times then my element should get inserted only once and not multiple times.

Example- `If i am running this 2 times`-

**Actual Output**-

```
<root>
<value1>somevalue</value1>
<value2>somevalue</value2>
<value3>somevalue</value3>
<value4>somevalue</value4>
<Root>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <C>C</C>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
</Root>
<Root>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <C>C</C>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
</Root>
<value5>Australia</value5>
<value6>India</value6>
<value7>USA</value7>
<value8>somevalue</value8>
<value9>somevalue</value9>
<value10>somevalue</value10>
</root>
```

**Expected Output-**

```
<root>
<value1>somevalue</value1>
<value2>somevalue</value2>
<value3>somevalue</value3>
<value4>somevalue</value4>
<Root>
    <A>A</A>
    <B>B</B>
    <C>C</C>
    <D>D</D>
    <E>E</E>
</Root>
<value5>Australia</value5>
<value6>India</value6>
<value7>USA</value7>
<value8>somevalue</value8>
<value9>somevalue</value9>
<value10>somevalue</value10>
</root>
```

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: You could wrap it in a try catch, where the try looks to see if the element exists and the catch creates it if it's missing.

Comment: Posted my exact query in a new Question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476912/how-to-insert-a-new-element-after-a-node-in-xquery

Answer (score 2):

Before inserting the node, check that it's not already there:

```
if (empty(child::Root)) then xdmp:update....
```

Comment: @Michael-- Thank you for your suggestion. The problem here i am facing is that if inside my element any node's value got changed (Example `<D>D</D> becomes <D>India</D>`)then i need not to make a second entry for that instead i need to update that entry alone.

Comment: Posted my exact query in a new Question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476912/how-to-insert-a-new-element-after-a-node-in-xquery

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are using  xdmp:node-insert-after -- this will do what the function name says (insert after)  each time its called.  As commented, you can conditionally call xdmp:node-update instead.  Alternatively you can use xquery directly:

```
doc("file.xml" )/root ! <root>{ ./*[ . << ./value4] , $element , $a/value4, ./*[. >> ./value4] }</root>
```

Note: the "<<" operator compares "document order" (position not value)

Comment: @DALDEI-- Your code looks bit complex to me :) but Thank you for your suggestion. The problem here i am facing is that if inside my element any node's value got changed (Example `<D>D</D> becomes <D>India</D>`)then i need not to make a second entry for that instead i need to update that entry alone.

Comment: Posted my exact query in a new Question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476912/how-to-insert-a-new-element-after-a-node-in-xquery